# Keeping a sum based on future operations

Tags: scala

The goal is to go through a list performing a future operation on each element of the list, and then sum the values that get returned by those future operations.

I'm trying to only use immutable data.

Something like this:

```
list.foldRight(0)((obj,sum) => {
  val c: Int = doFutureThing(obj)
  c + sum  // no good: c is a Future[Int]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use something like that:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Scratch {
  def operation(i: Int): Future[Int] = {
    Future.successful(i+1)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val list = List(1,2,3,4)
    val resultFuture = Future
      .sequence(list.map(operation))
      .transform(list => list.foldLeft(0)((x, y) => x+y), t => t)
    println(Await.result(resultFuture, Duration.Inf))
  }
}
```

Whats happening here:

1. The key idea is `Future.sequence`. It allows you to convert collection of futures into future of collection then operate with that collection in usual manner. So we use it to easier our job. Now we have `Future[List[Int]]` instead of `List[Future[Int]]`
2. We map our `Future[List[Int]]` onto `Future[Int]` using `transform` method. Actually, here we may use any transformations we wish, not only counting the sum.
3. We await for result of `Future[Int]` using implicit default execution context

The only problem with such approach may arise if your source collection is enormously large, so it can't fit your heap and you wish to apply operations when enough Futures of Int are ready (assuming that operation order is not important). If you wish to do so, answer should be a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with a collection of items...

```
val li = List(2, 4, 7)  // List[Int]
```

...and then transform it to a collection of futures...

```
import concurrent._
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val lfi = li.map(doFutureThing)  // List[Future[Int]]
```

...you can then reduce them to a single future item.

```
val fi = Future.reduce(lfi)(_+_)  // Future[Int]
```